# Azure SQL Database ARM - Parameter 'maxSizeBytes' must be of type 'int'

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-sql-server, azure-resource-group

When downloading a template through Azure Portal for creating a new SQL Database with Basic tier and a new SQL Server you get a parameter called `'maxSizeBytes'`. Using this template and parameters with a `Azure Resource Group` project in Visual Studio you get the error below:

> Parameter 'maxSizeBytes' must be of type 'int'

[image]

Given that a `int32` max value is `2,147,483,647` I tried to use one less byte. Validation then passed but I got an error during deploy instead:

> InvalidMaxSizeTierCombination: The tier 'Basic' does not support the
> database max size '2147483647'.

[image]

Comment: What's you VS version? I using Visual Studio 2019 and it works well.

Comment: @LeonYue Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.6.4

Comment: which visual studio template did you use,Blank?

Comment: @LeonYue Nope, created a new resource from Azure Portal then saved the template from `Download a template for automation`.

Comment: @Ogglas did you solve the issue?

Comment: @DanielBjörk Yes I did thank you. Changed parameter to string as in the example below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `template.json` change `maxSizeBytes` type to `string` instead of `int`.

```
"maxSizeBytes": {
    "type": "string"
},
```

In `parameters.json` change int value to a string:

```
"maxSizeBytes": {
    "value": "2147483648"
},
```

Then it worked for me:

[image]

Given that the template was downloaded raw from Azure I think it is weird this has to be done in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think its an Visual Studio bug. Try deploying with PowerShell (Az Module) and use the size: 2147483648

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -TemplateFile <path-to-template> -TemplateParameterFile <path-to-parameterfile>
```

The size needs to be 100MB, 500MB, 1GB or 2GB when using Basic SKU

If it works deploying using PowerShell without modifying the DataType then it proves that it is a Visual Studio bug.